# Python Pandas df.Unique display/print contents

Tags: python, excel, pandas, text, unique

I am very new to python and am running into an issue when I am trying to display the data frame I made from unique values in my excel column.

So what is happening is I try to write "aa" I get

```
[u'a' u'b' u'c' u'd' u'e' u'f']
```

when what I want is

```
a, b, c, d, e, f
```

or even

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

whichever is more straightforward.  My thought is that since I am using `str()` it is taking the data frame as is but, if I don't include `str()` when I write it I get

```
∞*

p!`!@‹!@˛
```

as output...

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(open('/Users/keatonmaclean/Desktop/abcc.xlsx','rb'), sheetname='Sheet1')
# Set ipython's max row display
pd.set_option('display.max_row', 1000)

# Set iPython's max column width to 50
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]

aa = str(df.loc[:,"Supplier"].unique())
#bb = str(df.loc[:,"CT #"].unique())
#cc = str(df.loc[:,"CT DESC"].unique())
#dd = str(df.loc[:,"CT START"].unique())
#ee = str(df.loc[:,"CT END"].unique())



import os.path

save_path = '/Users/keatonmaclean/Desktop/'

#name_of_file = raw_input("What is the name of the file: ")
name_of_file = "test"

completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")         

file1 = open(completeName, "w+")

toFile =  aa 


file1.write(toFile)

file1.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `DataFrame` or `Series` constructor with [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or [`Series.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html):

```
aa = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])

df = pd.DataFrame([aa])
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  a  b  c  d  e  f

df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Or if need one columns:

```
s = pd.Series(aa)
print (s)
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    e
5    f
dtype: object

s.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

But if need create file from all unique values is possible [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function `unique`.

But if different length of unique values per column get `NaN`s and in output `NaN`s are replace with empty space.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Supplier':list('abcceb'),
                   'CT #':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'CT DESC':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'CT START':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'CT END':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})

print (df)
   CT #  CT DESC  CT END  CT START Supplier
0     4        7       5         1        a
1     5        8       3         3        b
2     4        9       6         5        c
3     5        4       9         7        c
4     5        2       2         1        e
5     4        3       4         0        b

df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique())).astype(object)
print (df)
  CT # CT DESC CT END CT START Supplier
0    4       7      5        1        a
1    5       8      3        3        b
2  NaN       9      6        5        c
3  NaN       4      9        7        e
4  NaN       2      2        0      NaN
5  NaN       3      4      NaN      NaN

df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: The first suggestion seems to be the best option specifically "df = pd.DataFrame([aa])_ print (df)" then I found if i use "print df.to_string(index=False, header=False)" will remove the "0" on the left and the "0-5" above the values.  Thanks